# Removing duplicates with DISTINCT in standard SQL within BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, distinct, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to weed duplicates out of a table based on the column (that is created within the query) "alpha_ssc_key". However when I run this query, it just returns all of the results (instead of eliminating rows where the "alpha_ssc_key" is a duplicate). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is being done within BigQuery.

```
WITH ssc_test_view AS (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(date AS STRING), ciq_id, CAST(quantity AS STRING), CAST(cost_basis AS STRING),fund,security,class,inv_type,share_type) AS alpha_ssc_key,
    _metadata_created_at AS file_date,
    realized_gain_loss,
    cusip,
    acq_txn_no,
    acquisition_date,
    security,
    company,
    ticker,
    ciq_id,
    class,
    inv_type,
    dis_txn_no,
    quantity,
    categorization,
    transaction_type,
    cost_basis,
    share_type,
    fund,
    net_proceeds,
    unit_cost
  FROM
    `fcm-dw.acquisition_ssc.ssc_log`)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ssc_test_view
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISTINCT applied to ALL columns  - not just to your key  - that is why still all rows are returned. In your case better to group by fields from your compound key, but you need to decide on logic of actual deduping. In below example MIN is used. But you can use any aggregation function that fit in your needs

Try below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH ssc_test_view AS (
  SELECT
    date,
    ciq_id, 
    quantity, 
    cost_basis,
    fund,
    security,
    class,
    inv_type,
    share_type,
    MIN(_metadata_created_at) AS file_date,
    MIN(realized_gain_loss) AS realized_gain_loss,
    MIN(cusip) AS cusip,
    MIN(acq_txn_no) AS acq_txn_no,
    MIN(acquisition_date) AS acquisition_date,
    MIN(company) AS company,
    MIN(ticker) AS ticker,
    MIN(dis_txn_no) AS dis_txn_no,
    MIN(categorization) AS categorization,
    MIN(transaction_type) AS transaction_type,
    MIN(net_proceeds) AS net_proceeds,
    MIN(unit_cost) AS unit_cost,
  FROM `fcm-dw.acquisition_ssc.ssc_log`
  GROUP BY 
    date,
    ciq_id, 
    quantity, 
    cost_basis,
    fund,
    security,
    class,
    inv_type,
    share_type)
SELECT * FROM ssc_test_view
```

Comment: What is the min function doing in this case? Just taking the first instance?

Comment: it takes minimum value for respective field. as I mentioned - you can use any deduping logic - but you need to "select" only one value for those fields which are outside of grouping list

Comment: So realistically I could leave out aggregate logic like MIN(), because I am not trying to weed down based on those records, right? Imagine the key I have mentioned above is the field I want to use to dedupe this data-set. What should I use on that key to dedupe?

Comment: if you will try using GROUP BY without aggregation function for fields which are not part of GROUP BY  - you will get error

Comment: Sure I get it on that part. What I mean is, could I just group by the alpha_ssc_key, and use some other aggregate on the rest? I only want to group on that key, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: got it - yes, exactly . sounds right. you should try anyway :o)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT stv.*
FROM (SELECT stv.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY alpha_ssc_key ORDER BY _metadata_created_at DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ssc_test_view stv
     ) stv
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: What is stv.* representative of? or could you give me some insight on the logic here

Comment: @DaveChappelle . . . `stv` is a table alias, which wasn't correctly defined.